# Copiar projeto em NodeJs para outra máquina

Tags: node.js

Eu tenho o NodeJs instalado em 2 maquinas.

Preciso migrar o projeto de uma maquina para outra.

Basta copiar apenas a pasta do projeto ou na maquina destino terei que fazer algo?

Instalei vários módulos do Express 4, tenho que voltar a instalar na nova maquina ou copiar a pasta basta?

A minha preocupação é que mais a frente apareçam bugs devido a má migração.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Basta copiar apenas a pasta do projeto ou na maquina destino terei que fazer algo?

Se o seu projeto usa [`npm`](https://www.npmjs.org/), basta copiar o fonte inteiro do projeto e executar um `npm install` que tudo está pronto.

Comment: Sim, utiliza, essa era a minha duvida, se o npm install bastava. Obrigado.